# Can I use the wiring for a range hood for a new outlet?

Tags: wiring, kitchens

I took the stove hood down to remodel kitchen. I capped off the wires, but I would like to some some kind of outlet in the wall using these wires. Is this possible?

Comment: It goes without saying that ones does not splice wires not inside a junction box, and one does not bury any splice or junction box underneath drywall or anything that needs more than a screwdriver to remove and replace.    (Except of course for lamps, receptacles and things which attach to junction boxes).

Comment: Use something like Panduit's surface mount electrical raceways and boxes if you can't add a recessed outlet at that location

Answer (score 3):

Sure. They're (presumably) no different than would feed any standard outlet or light. Install a rated remodeler box and go nuts. You'll probably need to use a GFCI outlet if it's not already protected by one upstream.

Answer (score 0):

You could go up in the attic and pull out the wire to the range hood and reroute it to another location. If the wire is too short then terminate it in an electrical box in the attic and use a new piece of cable to where you want to go,

Probably the cable to this range hood is not on a dedicated circuit, but is a branch off a circuit. It might be better to remove this branch and establish a new one.